# Flag was declined but later it was found helpfull

Tags: discussion, flagging

I am writing this in content of [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/186637/get-value-from-json) post. I found that this question does not have any reason to be on [SE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/). This question is best suitable for [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/). So I raised the flag for the same. But my flag was declined. And Now that post is put on **Hold** for the same reason which I have reported.

But my flag still shows ***decline***.

[image].

Don't you think it should now again converted to **helpful**?

Correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, moderators can’t change declined flags to helpful flags afterwards. But if you want it corrected, flag the post again and I’ll mark it as helpful.

Comment: No I was just wanted to know whether there is any provision or not. Ultimately my goal achieved for flagging. :-)

Comment: @AakashMorya Nice! Keep those flags coming. We rely very much on them especially when we have so many new questions every day. Thanks!